# Conversion of very large string to integer format

Tags: c, string

I have a string of 200 characters( all of the characters are either 0 or 1) in input. Need a way to convert the characters to `int` format and store them in an array or variable.

Example: `"00101110010..." -> 00101110010...`

the code snippet below only works for <=20 character string.

```
    scanf("%u", &digit_num);   //number of digits in input number/string
    unsigned input_binary[digit_num]; //where the integers will be stored as individual digit
    unsigned long long temp; //temporary storage
    char crc[digit_num+1], *ptr=NULL;
    scanf(" %s", crc);
    temp=strtoull(crc,&ptr,10);
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < digit_num; j++)
    {
        input_binary[digit_num-j-1]=temp%10;
        temp/=10;
    }
```

Comment: int can't store 200 digit numbers, plus 0001 will be converted to 1, maybe an array of Bytes is what you should go for

Comment: that  is why I choose array in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
for (unsigned j = 0; j < digit_num; j++)
{
  input_binary[j]=crc[j]-48;
}
```

ASCII of '0' is 48.
char('3') - 48 = int(3)

Comment: I tried a similar way earlier in my code, but something was faulty there. now, with your code/help, it's working. thanks a lot

Comment: Use `'0'` instead of a literal 48. ASCII is highly likely but not guaranteed IIRC, plus Magic Numbers are Bad.